# How to find the Full path to a most recent added file using AppleScript?

Tags: xcode, shell, applescript, ios-ui-automation

I'm using Automator appleScript to upload new pictures to my Instagram.
The script trigger when new file is added to a folder `updates`

```
on adding folder items to myFolder after receiving FileList
    repeat with aFile in FileList
        activate application "Uploader HD for Instagram"
        delay 0.5
        delay 0.5

        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                click menu item "Open..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
            end tell
        end tell

        delay 1

        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
            delay 0.5
            keystroke myFolder
            delay 1
            delay 1
            keystroke return
            keystroke (ASCII character 31)
            delay 1
            keystroke return
            delay 1
            keystroke tab

        end tell

        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                click button "Post" of window "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                delay 1

                tell application "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                    quit
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell


        try

            tell application "Finder"

                delete (every item of folder myFolder whose name ends with ".jpg")

            end tell

        on error

            display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}

        end try

    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

I'm using the `var` `myFolder` to search the file using the "Go To the folder"
The `var myFolder` works but only gives me the path to the folder, and I need the path to the folder + File.ext

Any help will be much appreciated/

Thanks/.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand what you want to so, you want to open with Uploader HD application each file which is just added into a specific folder.

If this is correct, then just use Folder actions. each time new files will be added to the folder, the system will trigger the script, giving as argument only the files just added (and not the file already stored in that folder previously !). for each file added, you must just ask HD uploader to open it.

You must first assign the script bellow to your folder "Update" :

Copy / paste the script bellow into ScriptEditor and save it in your ~library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts

Right click on your folder (updates") and add this folder action script.

```
on adding folder items to myFolder after receiving FileList
repeat with aFile in FileList
    tell application "Uploader HD for Instagram" to open aFile
end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

I can't test with Instagram uploader (I don't have it). It could happen that some applications are not answering to an "open" command. If this is the case you may have to replace the line "tell application...open aFile" by an other method to open it. You can use the variable aFile which contains the complete path to the added file. aFile is an alias type and (aFile as string) is the string which you can use in your goto dialog box.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your work and It works but only the path to the folder, not the path to the file.. I already update my code It's working but using space + enter and tab to navigate and select the file.. which is  not the best option. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code, what I was missing is `POSIX`
The `var` `myFilePath` defined with `set` includes the full `path` to the `file`

```
on adding folder items to myFolder after receiving FileList
    try
        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in FileList
            repeat with aFile in FileList
                activate application "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                delay 0.5
                delay 0.5

                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                        click menu item "Open..." of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1
                    end tell
                end tell

                delay 0.5
                set myFilePath to POSIX path of item i of FileList
                tell application "System Events"
                    keystroke "G" using {command down, shift down}
                    delay 0.5
                    keystroke myFilePath
                    delay 0.5
                    keystroke return
                    delay 0.5
                    keystroke return
                    delay 0.5
                    keystroke tab
                    keystroke "#Instagood #Instagram #Luxury #Babe #Model #Follow @CindyJordanLove"
                end tell

                tell application "System Events"
                    tell process "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                        click button "Post" of window "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                        delay 1

                        tell application "Uploader HD for Instagram"
                            quit
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell


                try

                    tell application "Finder"

                        delete (every item of folder myFolder whose name ends with ".jpg")

                    end tell

                on error

                    display dialog ("Error. Couldn't Move the File") buttons {"OK"}

                end try
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end try
end adding folder items to
```